# PHP Laravel 5 elseif not behaving as expected

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-5

I have 2 variables that can either be filled with a value, be 'all' or be 'null'

Variable 1 is `$type` and variable 2 is `$brand`.

So if the user selects a type and a brand I want to query the cars accordingly. If the users selects nothing then the value is 'null' if the user selects 'all' then the value is 'all' obviously.

I've wrote the 4 scenario's out in commented code as follows:

```
//brand                 and type                -> get cars of brand and type
//brand = all or null   and type = all or null  -> get all cars
//brand                 and type = all or null  -> get cars of all types and brand
//brand = all or null   and type                -> get cars of all brands and type
```

this is my if structure:

```
if ($brand && $type) {
            $cars = Cars::where([
                ['cost', '<=', $budget],
                ['brand', '=', $brand],
                ['type', '=', $type]
            ])->get();
} elseif($brand == 'all' || $brand === null && $type == 'all' || $type === null) {
            $cars = Cars::where('cost', '<=', $budget)
                ->get();
} elseif($brand && $type == 'all' || $type === null) {
            $cars = Cars::where([
                ['cost', '<=', $budget],
                ['brand', '=', $brand],
            ])->get();
} elseif ($brand == 'all' || $brand === null && $type) {
            $cars = Cars::where([
                ['cost', '<=', $budget],
                ['type', '=', $type]
            ])->get();
}
```

Now when I check the value of `$brand` it's filled with `Audi` and `$type` is `null`.

Can someone please explain to me why I get the result of the first elseif?
So my code thinks this is the case:

`elseif($brand == 'all' || $brand === null && $type == 'all' || $type === null) {`

Which is weird because `$brand` is neither 'all' or 'null' since it's 'Audi'

Hope it's clear.

Comment: Use '===' for strict comparison, and swap every '===null' with a '!$variable'.

Comment: try this elseif(($brand == 'all' || $brand === null) && ($type == 'all' || $type === null))

Comment: @PedroFaria99 Thanks for your response but this doesn't change anything to the result I still end up in the wrong elseif

Comment: This is called [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: see answer below of @u_mulder

Answer (score 3):

According to [`operators precedence` table](http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php), your first `elseif` condition

```
$brand == 'all' || $brand === null && $type == 'all' || $type === null
```

is treated as:

```
($brand == 'all') || ($brand === null && $type == 'all') || ($type === null)
```

With values `$brand = Audi` and `$type = null` it is true:

```
(false || false || true) -> true
```

That's why you need to put parentheses so php can understand **your** logic and not apply it's own.

Answer (score 1):

You are really making your life harder. You have 2 independent variables affecting two independent conditions, there's no reason you should mix them in the same conditional.

```
$wheres = [  ['cost', '<=', $budget] ];
if ($brand !== "all" && $brand !== null) {
   $wheres[] = [ "brand", "=", $brand ];
}
if ($type !== "all" && $type !== null) {
   $wheres[] = [ "type", "=", $type ];
}
$cars = Cars::where($wheres);
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the way you wrote the condition is pretty wrong as I can understand!

'null' is not same as false or ''.'null' is an object.

Therefore, you can use it like:

$brand && $type
`if(!empty($brand) && !empty($type))`